# Is it necessary to put column:string on rails 3/4 generate model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

I saw in a post that was not necessary to specify the type string for some column. But it didn't say which Rails he was using and the ruby guide put the :string anyway. In which version is that required ?

Comment: what post did you see this in?

Comment: what do you mean by 'some'?

Comment: I don't know if it is necessary, but you have to set the type of the column in the DB, Rails can't decide for you (!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it's not necessary. Look [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/generated_attribute.rb#L55-L61), at the `Rails::Generators::GeneratedAttributes#initialize` source. You'll see the line:

```
@type           = type || :string
```

So if you omit column type in generating model, it will be set by default to string. 
Thanks, BTW, it was nice to learn.